# Django Rest Framework: How to Append to array

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a user object where I want to add a new friend onto their existing friends list. If below is the existing friends list for user1 , how would I POST/PUT a new friend onto that existing list without reposting the whole friends list.

```
    {
        "friends": [
            {
                "first_name": "Bob" 
            },
            {
                "first_name": "Dave" 
            },
            {
                "first_name": "Jon" 
            }

        ],
       "first_name": "User1", 
    }
```

What would my JSON look like in the POST and what do I have to do on the DRF end to allow me to update this array without reposting the existing array.

I tried to POST the following but it just overwrote the entire friend list

```
PATCH /api/profile/55522221111/ HTTP/1.1
{"friends":[{"first_name":"new friend"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off creating a new endpoint, something like:

```
POST /api/profile/555222211111/friends/add/
{
    "first_name": "new_friend"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to your strategy could be redefining your models so as to create a [one-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) reference of the inner objects in the array, which in your example has  `{"first_name": "Bob"}` in it to the main object.

This would allow you to post into the friends array just by mentioning a foreign key in model.

Something like :

> models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name    = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Friend(models.Model):
    first_name    = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    user          = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friends')
```

> serializers.py

```
class FriendSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Friend
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', )


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    friends = FriendSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'friends', )
```

> views.py

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class FriendViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FriendSerializer
```

> urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'friends', FriendViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

This should result in 2 urls like `(1) /api/users/` and  `(2) /api/friends/` and you can post into `(2)` and if references are correct it will show as you wish in `(1)`.

```
{
    "friends": [
        {
            "first_name": "Bob" 
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Dave" 
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Jon" 
        }

    ],
   "first_name": "User1", 
}
```